# React Redux - Why can't I easily set initialValues from this.props?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

So I've inherited a project in which I need to utilize `FieldArrays` to create a dynamic list of items. The "form" that it's in is not actually in a `<form>`, so therefore I've had to section off my `FieldArrays` code into its own component in order to let redux magically make it "work" to do the things I want it to do, such as prepopulate the fields with data, be able to add/remove fields easily, etc.

The problem is that I can't seem to pre-populate the component with the props from the higher up component so that the redux FieldArray can pick it up, no matter what I've tried.

Here is my code:

```
renderFlooring({ fields, meta: { touched, error, submitFailed } }) {

      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div className={styles.flooringHeading}>
              <h3> Site Specifications </h3>
              <button type="button" className={styles.add} onClick={() => fields.push({})}>Add Square Footage</button>
            </div>
            {(touched || submitFailed) && error && <span>{error}</span>}
            {fields.length === 0 &&
              <p className={styles.noFlooring}>No square footage or flooring type has been added.</p>
            }
          </div>
          <ul className={styles.sqFtList}>
            {fields.map((flooring, index) =>
              <li className={styles.card} key={index}>
                <div className="page-form__block">
                  <p> Estimate the total area of work in square feet </p>
                  <Field name={`${flooring}.square_footage`} onChange={this.changeFlooringSquareFootage} component={TextField} hintText="Square Feet" />
                </div>
                <div className="page-form__block">
                  <p> Enter Floor Type </p>
                  <Field name={`${flooring}.flooring_type`} onChange={this.changeFlooringType} component={TextField} hintText="Floor Type (VCT, Carpet, Vinyle)" />
                </div>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  title="Remove"
                  className={styles.remove}
                  onClick={() => {
                    fields.remove(index);
                    this.props.removeFlooring(index);
                  }}>Remove</button>
              </li>
            )}
          </ul>
        </div>
      );
    }



  render() {
    return (
      <FieldArray name="flooring" component={this.renderFlooring}/>
    );
  }
}

export default reduxForm({
  form: 'manageSquareFootageForm',
  initialValues: this.props.flooring
})(ManageSquareFootageForm);
```

The component in which this particular component is imporated looks like this:

```
<ManageSquareFootageForm
   changeFlooringType={this.changeFlooringType}
   changeFlooringSquareFootage={this.changeFlooringSquareFootage}
   removeFlooring={this.removeFlooring}
   flooring={this.props.flooring}
/>
```

I've even tried adding `initialValues` on my `<ManageSquareFootageForm>` but that ends up causing my `fields.push({})` functionality to stop working.

My data looks like the following:

```
[
   {square_footage: "500", flooring_type: "carpet"},
   {square_footage: "1000", flooring_type: "carpet"}
]
```

Is there anything I can do here that's straight-forward?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `reduxFrom HOC` is unaware of the component props, you do set the `initialValues` from prop like

```
const FootableForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'manageSquareFootageForm'
})(ManageSquareFootageForm);

export default connect((state, props) => ({
    initialValues: props.flooring 
  }))(FootableForm)
```

However, your Field are not generated on the initial load and hence won't get populated, you would rather make use of `change` function from ReduxForm update the values.

```
const defaultValues = { square_footage: "500", flooring_type: "carpet" }


class FieldArraysForm extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    const {flooring, change} = this.props;
    const {flooring: prevflooring} = prevProps;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(flooring));
    // Do nothing if no flooring, or no change to flooring
    if (!flooring || flooring === prevflooring) {
      return;
    }

    if (!prevflooring || flooring.length > prevflooring.length) {
      change('flooring', flooring.slice(0, flooring.length - 1).concat(defaultValues));
    }

  }
  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <FieldArray name="flooring" component={renderFlooring} />
      </form>
    );
  }
};


const FieldForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'fieldArrays', // a unique identifier for this form
  validate,
})(FieldArraysForm);

export default connect(state => ({
  flooring: (getFormValues('fieldArrays')(state) || {}).flooring
}))(FieldForm);
```

Check the working **[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7yqk14039)**

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, but after trying this code, it's still not populating my fields in my FieldArray. The code actually makes sense, an dI've also updated my question to show what the data looks like. It matches the names of the fields, so it should know to grab it. Is there anything else I'm missing here?

Comment: What is `name={\`${flooring}.square_footage\`}` supposed to do

Comment: from what I understand, that would let the fields know it's a sub-element of the flooring object that gets passed down, right?

Comment: I tried changing them to `name="square_footage"` and it still isn't doing it :/

Comment: can you just try, `fields.getAll().map` instead of the normal `fields.map`. Not sure if it will work

Comment: yeah `fields.getAll().map` didn't work :/ I just got an error about react timers and what not. What is going on with `FootableForm`? Does that need to be connected somewhere else?

Comment: OHH, I JUST realised that it is the one that needs to be connected. Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the code

Comment: That makes sense and I did that, but now, not only are the fields not showing up, when I click on the "Add square footage" button to execute a `fields.push({})`, it no longer adds another row of empty inputs and it gives no errors :/ I feel like this should be working haha

Comment: It seems that FieldArray doesn't understand initialValues properly when its dynamically created and you need to make use of change to update the values, I have created this codeSandbox for you https://codesandbox.io/s/m7yqk14039

you ca modify it to set default values from props, I guess. Let me know if your face troubles

Comment: So I don't know what happened, but the code you originally suggested ended up working! I have no idea haha, but thanks so much for all of your help :D